# Loading other .NET libraries from a C++/CLI library called by native code

Tags: .net, c++-cli, assembly-resolution

So I have three parts:

- Lib: A C# library, compiled for AnyCPU.
- BridgeLib: A C++/CLI library, compiled for x86. It exports a native C function called `bridgeEntry` and calls methods in Lib.
- NativeExe: A native C++ Win32 application that simply loads BridgeLib.dll and executes `bridgeEntry`.

Now I put them all into one directory and as expected, code from Lib is executed when I run NativeExe.

However, if I rearrange the directory structure like this:

```
├───exe
│       NativeExe.exe
│
└───libs
        BridgeLib.dll
        Lib.dll
```

things are a little bit different. Obviously running `NativeExe.exe` in the `exe` folder fails because it can't find `BridgeLib.dll`. But that can be resolved by going to the `libs` folder and running `..\exe\NativeExe.exe`. Now the application loads `BridgeLib.dll` and jumps to `bridgeEntry`. But now the CLR crashes with a `FileNotFoundException` because it's looking for `Lib.dll` in the executable's folder (`exe`) and not in the bridge library's folder `libs`.

This is just an overly simplified example and I can't change the directory structure. But how else could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C++/CLI library could handle [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) to properly specify the location of the C# assembly.  This event is fired by the CLR when it fails to find the assembly at runtime, and gives you a chance to load the assembly yourself.

Comment: This is just an overly simplified example, actually I don't know anything about the directory structure except the fact that the native executables and the .NET assemblies are in different directories. How would I determine the directory in the AssemblyResolve event?

Comment: @main-- You'd need to know where the .NET assembly is - *something* needs to provide that location, and if it's not in the normal paths, you need to be that something.